# what are the available options to transform xml documents using JAVA?

Tags: java, xml

I am aware that an input xml can be transformed to an output xml using xsl transformation. Is there any other approach by which this can be implemented using solely java without utilizing the xslt. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

there are different options to do this in java. Best option for this is to use [Java XML Transformation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html).

But if you don't want to use an xslt file in general you could read the xml with [JAXB](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) and producing output with [Apache velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/), but in this case you have to know the structure of input document (and implement respective classes), and spend some effort on velocity implementation.